# How to apply a signal filter (high pass/low pass) to sql data

Tags: sql, filter, signals

My database stores time series sensor data.  I am trying to apply a high-pass/low-pass filter to clean the data before I do further processing.  how can I do that in sql?
sample data:

`import numpy as np
a=(np.range(0,101))*0.1
b=np.sin(2*np.pi*0.1*a)+np.random.random(10)-0.5`

when ploted, the data look like the following:
[image: Sine function + noise]
After filtering, the data should look like this:
[image: filtered data]

What can I do the logics in sql?

Comment: This is not what SQL is designed for.  However, if you ask a question, you should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what *you* mean by such a filter.

Comment: I think you could use analytical functions (aka "window functions") to produce subgroups and average data using some kind of arbitrary math. As in, for each sample, get all samples around it (for example 100 ms before and 100 ms after) and produce an average on them.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to this is to create a view that can (pre)process you data. For example:

```
create view averaged_sample as
select 
  s.*,
  avg(t.value) as avg_value -- simple math to average
from sample s 
join sample r on r.time between s.time - interval 100 ms 
                            and s.time + interval 100 ms
group by s.id
```

This view will be computed on the fly and -- therefore -- will be slow to use. If you need this intermediate results often, you would benefit from materializing it, or generaring it to a secondary table that you could even index.

The `AVG()` function is just a simple math implementation. You can replace it with some other more interesting math.

Comment: avg is not what want. I need some numpy.signal filter function.  Is that possible? thanks

Comment: You don't mention what database engine you are using, but you can write a new "aggregate function" with complex logic on it. For example in PostgreSQL you can do it using `CREATE AGGREGATE ...`: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createaggregate.html